# Shortcut to delete current file in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to delete the active file in visual studio from the editor itself  with a keyboard shortcut without searching it in the solution explorer and deleting with the mouse?

This can be useful when refactoring, for example if I have

```
namespace Test
{
    public static class Class
    {
    }
}
```

resharper will suggest to remove the unused class but the file can't be deleted

Comment: Use "Sync with Active Document" in the Solution Explorer (or its shortcut), then hit the "Delete" key. This button is in the row of buttons at the top of the Solution Explorer, and looks like two horizontal arrows pointing in opposite directions.

Comment: "Sync with Active Document" in VS2017 looks only available in folder view which I don't use

Comment: Here? https://imgur.com/0s61Rbe . I don't use the folder view either.

Comment: I don't have it, probably then due the initial setup

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->General`, check `Track Active Item in Solution Explorer`.

[image]

This will highlight the file in Solution Explorer, when the file is opened in the editor.
Use solution explorer shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, then use `Delete` or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> key to delete the file.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for